# Help Needed with Date Format in java

Tags: java

I have My Database data in this format

18-NOV-10

I have to pass the same format into java.util.Date like this

Date date = new java.util.Date(dateformater);

so that the result of java.util.Date is like this 18-NOV-10

Is this possible ??

I tried this way

```
String strDate = "12-NOV-07";

    SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");

    Date date = sdfSource.parse(strDate);

    System.out.println(date);
```

But i am getting the result as "Mon Nov 12 00:00:00 IST 2007 " which i want it only
12-NOV-07"

Comment: You are storing dates in your database as text and not as DateTime?

Comment: You start with "12-NOV-07" and the desired result is "12-NOV-07"? I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you should probably store your dates as dates, not strings; nevertheless...

If you want to turn a `Date` back into a string in that format you can use the following:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
Date date = new Date();
String dateStr = formatter.format(date); // Gives "22-May-11"
```

If you need MAY instead of May, just use `toUpperCase()` on the resultant string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java.text.DateFormat (actually SimpleDateFormat) to get you where you want to go, but maybe you shouldn't be storing the dates as strings in your database.  It will do output and parsing.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf =
            new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-YY");
Date parsed = sdf.parse(dateString);
```

See http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/

Once you get the Date, you can turn it into the format you want but it will be held in memory as a Date object.  You can get it in the form you want using

```
String dateString = sdf.format(parsed);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
Date d = sdf.parse("18-NOV-10");
```

Comment: I tried your program , but i am getting Thu Nov 18 00:00:00 IST 2010 where i want only as 18-NOV-10

Comment: I don't understand you need that string only then why you want to convert into date?

Comment: I have a Method List getSummary(Date fromDate, Date toDate) , this is in java.util.Date Format and the Data in data base is 18-NOV-11 format

Comment: I would suggest you not to store date as string in DB, and for now the answer is `sdf.format(d);`

Answer (score 0):

Try `System.out.println(sdfSource.format(date).toUpperCase());` instead. The `Date` object will always have a time component to it; there is no way to "disable" that feature. What you can do instead is to ignore it in your calculations and display. If all `Date` objects you use are set to the same time of the day, then you can safely ignore the effect of the time component in your comparisons. If you look carefully, the time component of your `Date` object is set to midnight.